# JOptionPane.showinputdialog opening twice in applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, java-2d

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    myWidth = getSize().width; // get this Applet size
    myHeight = getSize().height;
    double xCoord, yCoord;
    int yPixel;
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name.");
    g.drawString(str, 100, 100);

    for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < myWidth; xPixel++) {
        xCoord = (double) (xPixel - myYAxisHPos) / myXUnitPixels;
        yCoord = f(xCoord);
        yPixel = (int) (myXAxisVPos - yCoord * myYUnitPixels);
        g.drawLine(xPixel, yPixel, xPixel, yPixel);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why it opens twice when I start my applet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 3):

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
 ..
 String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name.");
```

Never change the GUI or pop a modal dialog within the `paint(Graphics)` method!  The latter  will block the EDT and the both will cause a loop.

> I'm wondering why it opens twice when I start my applet

Paint might be called at any time, it is not within the programmer's control.

Instead, the method should be moved to the `init()` method, and the result stored as a class attribute.

Something like:

```
String str = null;

@Override
public void init() {
  str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name.");
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you call `paint` method using draw method normally `paint`() method is call by the JVM you can't control that. Don't use a JOptionPane inside that. Every time `frame` or `panel` get refresh `paint` method will get call.